# What is the difference between subdivision and Meshing?

Tags: modifiers

[image][[image: Subdivision ModifierRe-Meshing]The first image is a Cube that has been Re-meshed. The second image is a Cube that I applied Subdivision Modifier. When I subdivided a cube, an object with several faces appeared within the cube. An outline of the cube was maintained with the new object.  I changed the subdivisions and ended up with a sphere within the cube.  I am extremely puzzled, the Manual did not make it any clearer.  I know we re-mesh to increase the number of surfaces to which texture will be applied smoothly.  I must have watched a video that used the terms interchangeably.  Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

I apologize if I messed up the images, this is my first time uploading pic on this platform:

Comment: Remesh is usually a term associated with converting a model with "messy" topology (containing tri's and n-gon's), and converting it back to quads. It can also refer to changing the number of subdivisions of a mesh or how the divisions are calculated. Subdivision surface modifier, on the other hand, subdivides each quad into 4 quads, and if set to "catmull clark", attempts to interpolate (curve) the angles between adjoining faces so as to provide a "rounded" result. The terms are generally not used interchangeably except in certain scenarios.

Comment: We have 3 terms here, none of which are really interchangeable.  According to Google:
*Meshing -- or mesh generation -- is the process of generating polygonal or polyhedral mesh (i.e., the shape of the polygon/polyhedral is made up of multiple edges, faces and vertices).* 

So meshing is a  broad category of "mesh generation".   It doesn't describe a specific geometry, use case, or tool.

On the other hand,  we have the two modifiers in Blender, the **Subdivision** modifier and **Remesh**, which are not general terms, but very specific to Blender.  Best to experiment with these modifiers.

Comment: You refer to images, but you forgot to attach them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To graphically show the differences, here are some examples.

here are pictures of a base model, simple, and then Catmull subdivision:[image]

Here is the same model with the remesh modifier applied, blocks, smooth, sharp, Voxel:

[image]

Finally, the same base model, with Voxel and quad flow remesh:

[image]

This is not a precise answer, but at least it gives you a way of visually contrasting the techniques all of which "generate mesh".